# How to make user attributes from AWS userpool updateable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

I am trying to update attributes from users from a AWS Cognito userpool with AWS Amplify.

```js
try {
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
        'nickname': 'newtestname'
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
InvalidParameterException: user.nickname: Attribute cannot be updated.
```

I would expect it to be updateable because I made the attributes writable in the userpool-client section in my SAM template:

```yaml
WriteAttributes:
        - email
        - nickname
UserPoolId: !Ref MyCognitoUserPool
```

This is also reflected correctly in the console:
[image]

I have no app client secret and all auth flows enabled. The security configuration is set to enabled.
Users can register, so I assume that the Amplify config in the client is alright.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. On creation of the userpool I had to set the `mutable` flag within the schema definition, like so:

```yaml
Schema: 
  - Name: email
    Mutable: true
    ...
  - Name: nickname
    Mutable: true
    ...
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPool.html